# Shift elbow arrow to make space to another arrow

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am having an issue to shift the arrow to the "Process Model" so to make space for another one going from the "Measuring Process" to the "Process Model" (through a bunch of other boxes not included).

I could probably do it by shifting the intermediate node at the elbow of the arrow, but it seems just a bad hack. Any suggestion on how to do it better?

Also, is there a better way to increase the side of *all* the arrow heads? the use of `postaction` also feels a bit of a "hack".

[image]

Minimal working example below:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}

\tikzset{
  joinnode/.style={draw, circle, fill=black, minimum size=0.15cm, inner sep=0cm},
  boxnode/.style={draw, fill=white, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1.2cm, align=center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={
      markings,
      mark=at position 1 with {\arrow[scale=2,black]{stealth}};
    }
  ]

\node[boxnode] (process) at (0,0) {Process};
 
\node (startnode) at (-5,0) {};
 
\draw[postaction={decorate}] (startnode.east) -- (process.west) node[midway,above] {Input data} node[midway,joinnode] (input) {};

%\node [jointnode, right=1.5cm of process] (node1) {};

\draw[postaction={decorate}] (process.east) -- (5,0) node[midway, above] {Sensor Data} node[pos=0.7, joinnode] (node1) {};

\node[boxnode, below=1cm of node1] (measure) {Measurement\\ Processing};

\draw[postaction={decorate}] (node1) -- (measure.north);

\node[boxnode, below=2.5cm of process] (model) {Process\\ Model};

\node[inner sep=0cm, minimum width=0cm] at (input |- model) (node2) {};

\draw (input) -- ([yshift=+0.25cm]node2);

\draw[postaction={decorate}] (node2) -- ([yshift=+0.25cm]model.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a sketch how the result should look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, if you draw the path with `|-` instead of connecting an intermediate node, it creates a path with a rectangular angle at the position including the yshift at the target node.

Second, using the tikz library arrows.meta, you can configure the arrow heads without post action (e.g., `scale`, or `length` and `width`).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings, arrows.meta}

\tikzset{
  joinnode/.style={draw, circle, fill=black, minimum size=0.15cm, inner sep=0cm},
  boxnode/.style={draw, fill=white, minimum width=2cm, minimum height=1.2cm, align=center}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[boxnode] (process) at (0,0) {Process};
 
\node (startnode) at (-5,0) {};
 
\draw[-{Stealth[scale=2]}] (startnode.east) -- (process.west) node[midway,above] {Input data} node[midway,joinnode] (input) {};

\draw[-{Stealth[scale=2]}] (process.east) -- (5,0) node[midway, above] {Sensor Data} node[pos=0.7, joinnode] (node1) {};

\node[boxnode, below=1cm of node1] (measure) {Measurement\\ Processing};

\draw[-{Stealth[scale=2]}] (node1) -- (measure.north);

\node[boxnode, below=2.5cm of process] (model) {Process\\ Model};

\draw[-{Stealth[scale=2]}] (input) |- ([yshift=+0.25cm]model.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image: PDF Output]